# Jquery: check if cells are aligned horizontally, vertically, or diagonally

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a 6x7 table and when I click on a particular cell, I need to check if :
- 4 consecutive cells on the same row or 
- 4 consecutive cells on the same column or 
- 4 consecutive cells on the same diagonal
have an attribute class of blue.

I gave it a shot and it seems like the horizontal and the vertical checks work fine. But not the diagonal one. Any ideas?

```js
$(".circle").click(function() {

  var colindex = $(this).closest('td').index() + 1;
  var rowindex = $(this).closest('tr').index() + 1;

  if(checkHorizontally() || checkVertically() || checkDiagonally()){
      console.log("Blue wins");
  }

  function checkHorizontally(){
    var sum;
    for(i=6;i>0;i--){
      for(j=1;j<=7;j++){
        var cell = $('tr:nth-child('+i+') td:nth-child('+j+')');
        if (cell.find('div').css('background-color')==='rgb(0, 0, 255)'){
           sum+=1;
        }
        else{
           sum=0;
        }
        if(sum>=4){
          console.log("blue wins horizontally");
          return true;
        }
      }
      sum=0;
    }
  }

function checkVertically(){
  var sum;
  for(i=1;i<=7;i++){
    for(j=1;j<=6;j++){
      var cell = $('tr:nth-child('+j+') td:nth-child('+i+')');
      if (cell.find('div').css('background-color')==='rgb(0, 0, 255)'){
        sum+=1;
      }
      else{
        sum=0;
      }

    if(sum>=4){
      console.log("blue wins vertically");
      return true;
    }
  }
  sum=0;
  }
}

function checkDiagonally(){
  var sum;

  for(k=1;k<=7;k++){  
    for(var y=1, x=k; x<7 ; y++,x++){
      var cell = $('tr:nth-child('+y+') td:nth-child('+x+')');
      if (cell.find('div').css('background-color')==='rgb(0, 0, 255)'){
        sum+=1;
      }
      else{
        sum=0;
      }

    if(sum>=4){
      console.log("blue wins diagonally");
      return true;
    }
  }
  sum=0;
  }
}

    });
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #706e6e;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.circle.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ... 3 consecutive circles including the clicked one and connected to the clicked one? that was my first interpretation. please clarify

Comment: Yes including the clicked one

Comment: I don't understand, why, do you want to check the entire length instead of only the adjacent cells - If you're building a game (?) than it's unnecessary. Imagine you have a 100x100 grid, why iterate over 100(*4) cells  instead of only focusing on the adjacent ones - in a capped 5x5 box??

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying to do. Check the adjacent cells vertically, horizontally and diagonally

Comment: @SofiaLazrak something like this just limiting the set to 5? https://jsbin.com/qiyixineve/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: @SofiaLazrak did you check the code snippet in my answer? does it disqualify because you can't have coordinates?

Comment: @Bobbey In your answer, if a **variable** changes, say the number of consecutives, would that force a programmer to go add, copy-paste, tweak, and modify most of your code?

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan yes, its a specific approach for the number of consecutives being 3 and the same 6x7 grid. i didnt think of the number of consecutives being a variable... at least i wanted to give away one approach for the thread opener to do this check. i didnt target a general solution. it's implemented only for horizontals but you should get the idea and be able to adapt it to verticals and diagonals... well, at least you did give me a perspective why to downvote this.

Comment: @Bobbey thank you for your code but it is indeed a very specific approach as mentioned by Roko C. It is also too far fetched in my opinion. What I am trying to do is simple enough for an experimented programmer. I did add some functions to check in all directions. The diagonal check is not working yet. any input will be welcome.

Comment: @Sofia Lazrak You want to check the entire board for combinantions after each click. Thats a waste of time in my opinion. But okay, despite of that unneccesary work you changed 3 consecutive cells to 4 in your question... You wanted a generalized, easy to handle solution for adjacent n-tuples of circles. Thats not the easy kind of Programmers work, and i wouldnt expect to get such things implemeted for free on stackoverflow. deleted the specific approach.

Comment: @Bobbey not looking for free implementations. On the opposite I was trying with the help of stackoverflow community to get my own code working. Taking on personal and unpaid projects of my own to learn better programming practices and javascript (which I am new at). And I am thankful that there are always people willing to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution. I implemented two functions, one that checks if 4 cells are aligned from top left and one that checks from the bottom right. Both starting at the fourth row  because there are no 4 consecutive cells before that 4th row.

```
function checkDiagonally(color){

    var numRows = $('table tr').length;
    var numCols = $( "table tr:last td" ).length;
    for (var j = 4; j < numCols ; j++)
    {
        for (var i = 1 ; i <= 4; i++)
        {
          var cell1 = $('tr:nth-child('+j+') td:nth-child('+i+')');
          var cell2 = $('tr:nth-child('+(j-1)+') td:nth-child('+(i+1)+')');
          var cell3 = $('tr:nth-child('+(j-2)+') td:nth-child('+(i+2)+')');
          var cell4 = $('tr:nth-child('+(j-3)+') td:nth-child('+(i+3)+')');
          if (cell1.find('div').css('background-color')===color &&
              cell2.find('div').css('background-color')===color &&
              cell3.find('div').css('background-color')===color &&
              cell4.find('div').css('background-color')===color){
                return true;
          }
        }
      }
    }


function checkDiagonallyRTL(color){

    var numRows = $('table tr').length;
    var numCols = $( "table tr:last td" ).length;
    for (var j = 4; j < numCols ; j++)
    {
      for (var i = 7 ; i >= 4; i--)
      {
          var cell1 = $('tr:nth-child('+j+') td:nth-child('+i+')');
          var cell2 = $('tr:nth-child('+(j-1)+') td:nth-child('+(i-1)+')');
          var cell3 = $('tr:nth-child('+(j-2)+') td:nth-child('+(i-2)+')');
          var cell4 = $('tr:nth-child('+(j-3)+') td:nth-child('+(i-3)+')');
          if (cell1.find('div').css('background-color')===color &&
              cell2.find('div').css('background-color')===color &&
              cell3.find('div').css('background-color')===color &&
              cell4.find('div').css('background-color')===color){
                return true;
          }
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

We check whether the item is actually blue. If not, then the game is not won. Otherwise we check for items in the 4 directions. We have three cases in all four directions, depending on the position of the item in the pattern we check for.

```
 function check(item) {
    if (!item.hasClass("blue")) return false;

    var td = item.parent();
    var tr = td.parent();
    var tds = tr.find("td");
    var tdIndex = tds.index(td);
    var trParent = tr.parent();
    var trs = trParent.find("tr");
    var trIndex = trs.index(tr); //Initializing helper variables for the rows and columns
    if (tds.length >= 3) {
        if (tdIndex >= 2) {
            if (td.prev().find(".circle.blue").length && td.prev().prev().find(".circle.blue").length) return true;
        }
        if (tdIndex < tds.length - 2) {
            if (td.next().find(".circle.blue").length && td.next().next().find(".circle.blue").length) return true;
        }
        if ((tdIndex > 0) && (tdIndex < tds.length - 1)) {
            if (td.prev().find(".circle.blue").length && td.next().find(".circle.blue").length) return true;
        }
    }
    if (trs.length >= 3) {
        if (trIndex >= 2) {
            if ($(tr.prev().find("td")[tdIndex]).find(".circle.blue").length && $(tr.prev().prev().find("td")[tdIndex]).find(".circle.blue").length) return true;
        }
        if (trIndex < trs.length - 2) {
            if ($(tr.next().find("td")[tdIndex]).find(".circle.blue").length && $(tr.next().next().find("td")[tdIndex]).find(".circle.blue").length) return true;
        }
        if ((trIndex > 0) && (trIndex < trs.length - 1)) {
            if ($(tr.prev().find("td")[tdIndex]).find(".circle.blue").length && $(tr.next().find("td")[tdIndex]).find(".circle.blue").length) return true;
        }
    }
    if ((trs.length >= 3) && (tds.length >= 3)) {
        if ((trIndex >= 2) && (tdIndex >= 2)) {
            if ($(tr.prev().find("td")[tdIndex - 1]).find(".circle.blue").length && $(tr.prev().prev().find("td")[tdIndex - 2]).find(".circle.blue").length) return true;
        }
        if ((trIndex >= 2) && (tdIndex < tds.length - 2)) {
            if ($(tr.prev().find("td")[tdIndex + 1]).find(".circle.blue").length && $(tr.prev().prev().find("td")[tdIndex + 2]).find(".circle.blue").length) return true;
        }
        if ((trIndex < trs.length - 2) && (tdIndex >= 2)) {
            if ($(tr.next().find("td")[tdIndex - 1]).find(".circle.blue").length && $(tr.next().next().find("td")[tdIndex - 2]).find(".circle.blue").length) return true;
        }
        if ((trIndex < trs.length - 2) && (tdIndex < tds.length - 2)) {
            if ($(tr.next().find("td")[tdIndex + 1]).find(".circle.blue").length && $(tr.next().next().find("td")[tdIndex + 2]).find(".circle.blue").length) return true;
        }
        if ((trIndex > 0) && (trIndex < trs.length - 1) && (tdIndex > 0) && (tdIndex < tds.length - 1)) {
            if (
                ($(tr.prev().find("td")[tdIndex - 1]).find(".circle.blue").length && $(tr.next().find("td")[tdIndex + 1]).find(".circle.blue").length) ||
                ($(tr.prev().find("td")[tdIndex + 1]).find(".circle.blue").length && $(tr.next().find("td")[tdIndex - 1]).find(".circle.blue").length)
               ) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I would like to know why this answer was downvoted. Downvotes without explanation are not necessarily easy to understand.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thanks for the criticism. 0. fixed. 1. fixed. 2. At the time of writing my answer, there were no mentions of diagonals. Nevertheless, this was fixed. 3. Fixed. 4. Fixed.